# JSON PHP: Is this the correct way?

Tags: php, json

I just wanted some input about my use of JSON.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

//results
$results = array();
for($i=0;$i<20;$i++)
{
    $result = array();
    $result['name'] = 'Test Season '.ceil(($i+1)/13).' Episode '.(($i%13)+1);
    //$result['torrent'] = 'https://www.example.com/?id='.$i.'&key='.uniqid();
    $result['torrents'] = array();
        $c = mt_rand(1,4);
        for($j=0;$j<$c;$j++)
        {
            $torrent = array();
            $torrent['url'] = 'https://www.example.com/?id='.uniqid().'&key='.md5(uniqid());
            $torrent['codec'] = $j%2 == 0 ? 'xvid' : 'h264';
            $torrent['resolution'] = '720p';
            $result['torrents'][] = $torrent;
        }
    $results[] = $result; //push
}
echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

This is just some test code, not an actual implementation. Am I using JSON correctly and too the fullest? Or is some better method of doing this?

I have *legal* torrents that I'd like to do some JSON with.
Torrents are grouped by name which contain multiple torrents (actual links to data). And other information such as codec etc.

This is my first time actually outputting JSON, would XML be better?

Are there any guides on this topic (hopefully not entire books)?

Thanks.

Comment: you should use Content-type: application/json as header btw I don't know other ways to do that...

Comment: Ah I forgot about using that content type.

Comment: JSON is just a different way of representing the same data (as the name implies: javascript object NOTATION). If you are just using it for simple arrays like these, JSON will do perfectly fine.

Comment: @MiPnamic btw there is useful snippet on devzone to set the JSON header right that it doesn't get cached http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/5882

Comment: @Jeremy S. thank you so much =) I'll keep it in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you doing is right. I like to use the StdClass to make objects rather than key value arrays, just cause it looks sexier! E.g.

```
$torrent = new StdClass();
$torrent->url = 'https://www.example.com/?id='.uniqid().'&key='.md5(uniqid());
$torrent->codec = $j%2 == 0 ? 'xvid' : 'h264';
$torrent->resolution = '720p';
$result['torrents'][] = $torrent;
```

As you say you don't need to read a whole book on the matter, I would have a look here http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php to get to grips with the basics of JSON.

In terms of JSON vs XML, I find it far easier to represent data as JSON as it is easier to fetch the specific data you want much in the same way you can access the info in a stdClass object.

**[EDIT]**
And as Stefan Gehrig says make sure you define your content type as "application/json".

Comment: Oh that looks cool, I know PHP converts arrays to objects with json_encode but I must admit that looks nice. I'll research what StdClass actually is, I've never heard of it.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely fine. You could only change the MIME type to be [RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) compliant though: `application/json`.